# UTF-8 over HTTPS does not work but does over HTTP

Tags: http, utf-8, https

I'm having trouble to understand why the text of a simple PHP pages look fine when I visit it via HTTP, but is distorted when I visit it via HTTPS.

The page holds Greek text, the encoding of the file is UTF-8, and I have the content meta tag inside the HTML header:

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
```

What could the cause of this be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTP vs HTTPS typically has no effect on the character encoding of a webpage, as HTTPS merely encrypts the socket connection, nothing more.  Bytes are still transferred from the webserver to the webbrowser as-is, just encrypted.  So if the webpage is rendering differently under HTTPS than it does under HTTP, the webserver is sending different data under each protocol.

In your particular situation, that is actually the case.  Under HTTP, the webserver is sending UTF-8 encoded HTML and an HTTP `Content-Type: text/html` header with no charset specified, which allows the webbrowser to use the UTF-8 charset that is specified in the HTML's `meta` tag.

However, under HTTPS, the webserver is sending UTF-8 encoded HTML and an HTTP `Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-15` header instead.  That charset in the HTTP header overrides the UTF-8 charset in the HTML's `meta` tag, as HTTP headers get priority.  If you tell your webbrowser to ignore the HTTPS-delivered `Content-Type` charset and force the HTML to be interpretted as UTF-8, it renders the same way as the HTTP-delivered webpage.  So the problem is that your webserver is sending a faulty charset in the `Content-Type` header under HTTPS but not under HTTP.  The HTML itself is fine in both cases.  So either the webserver is not configured correctly, or the PHP script has a charset bug in it when sending data over HTTPS.

Comment: +1 Nice diagnosis. I'd add that it is likely that the HTTPS server is simply adding some default charset to responses that do not specify a charset. If the script were modified to set the correct charset in the content-type header, then the problem is likely to go away.

Comment: Thank yo both for your answer. It seems that that was the case, the webserver was injecting the iso-8859-16 charset. I managed to correct this by entering a php header call: header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');